# Fancy border in a HTML table

Tags: html, css

So I am styling a table, and I'd like to make quite a fancy underline for the table headings.

I've though hard and had a look on the internet but couldn't find anything.

This is the table structure:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

And my current styling:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

    table thead {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

        table thead td {
            margin-right: 5px;
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 10px 5px;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #427AA8;
        }

    table tbody {
        font-size: 90%;
    }

        table tbody tr {
            line-height: 2em;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
        }

        table tbody td {
            padding: 0 5px;
        }
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/tYA4e/1/

What I am looking for is a break in the border between the columns, but only in the thead.

And an example of what I am trying to achieve: http://i.imgur.com/OHrhJ.jpg

Is there a way to achieve this with some simple `CSS`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A border will, necessarily, extend the full width of its element; therefore to extend a border only partially across the width of an element that border must be applied to a child element, sized accordingly.

That said, the only way this is achievable would seem to be with nesting an element within the `td` (in this case a `span`), and using the following CSS:

```
table thead td span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #427AA8;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tYA4e/2/).

As an aside, though, it's worth noting that, for table-headings, the `th` (table-heading) element might be more appropriate for your use in this case.

On further thought it is, of course, also possible to use styled `hr` elements, which allows you to give pixel-level control over the `hr`'s width in that it can extend up to, in this example, `10px` from the right edge of the parent `td`):

```
table thead td hr {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #427AA8;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tYA4e/3/).

Comment: I think my preference is towards the `span` solution, I imagine it'd work more consistently in all browsers. But thanks for posting both solutions.

Comment: You're very welcome; I'm glad to have been (hopefully) of help! =)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use th for heading cells -> no more need for seperating the rows into groups with thead and tbody - less markup and less css.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>headlinecell</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>contentcell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

now just style the th and td.

Comment: It may end up as quite a large project, so although I agree with you I'm using this mark-up as it makes it quite clear to other developers what's going on.

Comment: Every browser I've worked with will, in the absence of a `tbody` element, insert one into the `table`. While the spec doesn't mandate its presence, it will be there once the DOM is constructed. That being the case, it's worth while inserting the `tbody`, `thead` and `tfoot` elements as appropriate, if only to make JavaScript manipulation and CSS presentation more predictable and consistent.

Comment: jquery selectors for example will work flawlessly with this structure. CSS will apply perfectly.